# How do I declare an array of arrays of different sizes in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, declaration

I essentially want to do something like this:

```
Foo one;
Foo two;
Foo three;

Foo **arr[] = {
    {&one, &two, NULL},
    {&one, NULL},
    {&one, &two, &three, NULL},
    NULL
};
```

That is, I want to declare a null terminated array of null terminated arrays of pointers to instances of a particular class.

This is for the Arduino environment, so `new`, `malloc()` and STL aren't available.

Comment: I know the declarations above are probably wrong for what I've written there in English, that's specifically what I'm asking for, the correct declarations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right path, but at core language level you will have to create named array objects for each sub-array

```
Foo one;
Foo two;
Foo three;

Foo *row0[] = { &one, &two, NULL };
Foo *row1[] = { &one, NULL };
Foo *row2[] = { &one, &two, &three, NULL };

Foo **arr[] = { row0, row1, row2, NULL };
```

(add `const` qualifiers as necessary).

In C you'd have *compound literal* feature that would allow you to do exactly what you have in your version

```
Foo **arr[] = 
{ 
  (Foo *[]) { &one, &two, NULL },
  (Foo *[]) { &one, NULL },
  (Foo *[]) { &one, &two, &three, NULL },
  NULL 
};
```

But it is a C-specific feature, not present in C++. You might want to check if your compiler supports it in C++ as a non-standard extension.

Comment: Oh damn. That's what I've got now, but I was trying to eliminate the redundancy. There's really no better way, eh?